# How to determine which variable agrees best with a gold standard?

Tags: t-test, agreement-statistics

I have a dataset of 100 patients. Each patient has 3 lab tests:

- Lab Test 0:  "Gold Standard" test which will serve as my reference standard
- Lab Test 1
- Lab Test 2

I want to compare the differences between Lab Test1 and Lab Test 0  and then Lab Test2 against Lab Test 0, with the aim at looking what the difference is between the values, and which one comes closer to Lab Test 0 on average.

Comment: Do you only want to know if the mean of the distribution of test 1 scores is closer to the mean of the gold standard, or do you want to know about the agreement of the variables as a whole? What kind of data are these test scores? Eg, are they roughly normal, or are they ordinal (normal, marginal, poor), or something else?

Comment: @gung I think I am going for the agreement of the variables as a whole, although maybee a comparison of the means is just as useful.   As for the variables, they are numerical blood test #s (mg/cc), so they can range from 0 to around 2000

Comment: What is the outcome of the test ? Binary ? continuous ? Continuous that is converted to binary ?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider Bland-Altman plots, and potentially Deming regression.

Comment: Thanks for contributing and welcome! Bland-Altman plots are definitely a good solution, but we like to encourage detail and explanation in our answers whenever possible. For instance, Bland-Altman plots can be tricky to understand; maybe you could add some intuition or tips for using them.